# Why won't the data be stored in my database?

Tags: php, mysql, eclipse

Sorry I am new to php so please be patient with me. I am creating a user interface and when I register it says I have registered but it doesn't store the data into the database. can someone please help me!

```
 <?PHP
$uname = "";
$pword = "";
$errorMessage = "";
$num_rows = 0;

function quote_smart($value, $handle) {

   if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
       $value = stripslashes($value);
   }

   if (!is_numeric($value)) {
       $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value, $handle) . "'";
   }
   return $value;
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){


    $uname = $_POST['username'];
    $pword = $_POST['password'];

    $uname = htmlspecialchars($uname);
    $pword = htmlspecialchars($pword);

    $uLength = strlen($uname);
    $pLength = strlen($pword);

    if ($uLength >= 10 && $uLength <= 20) {
        $errorMessage = "";
    }
    else {
        $errorMessage = $errorMessage . "Username must be between 10 and 20 characters" . "<BR>";
    }

    if ($pLength >= 8 && $pLength <= 16) {
        $errorMessage = "";
    }
    else {
        $errorMessage = $errorMessage . "Password must be between 8 and 16 characters" . "<BR>";
    }



    if ($errorMessage == "") {

    $user_name = "root";
    $pass_word = "";
    $database = "user authentication";
    $server = "127.0.0.1";

    $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $pass_word);
    $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

    if ($db_found) {

        $uname = quote_smart($uname, $db_handle);
        $pword = quote_smart($pword, $db_handle);


        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE USERNAME = $uname";
        $result = mysql_query($SQL);
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

        if ($num_rows > 0) {
            $errorMessage = "Username already taken";
        }

        else {

            $SQL = "INSERT INTO login (L1, L2) VALUES ($uname, md5($pword))";

            $result = mysql_query($SQL);

            mysql_close($db_handle);

        //=================================================================================
        //  START THE SESSION AND PUT SOMETHING INTO THE SESSION VARIABLE CALLED login
        //  SEND USER TO A DIFFERENT PAGE AFTER SIGN UP
        //=================================================================================

            session_start();
            $_SESSION['login'] = "1";

            header ("Location: page1.php");

        }

    }
    else {
        $errorMessage = "Database Not Found";
    }




    }

}


?>

    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Basic Login Script</title>


    </head>
    <body>


<FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="POST" ACTION ="signup.php">

Username: <INPUT TYPE = 'TEXT' Name ='username'  value="<?PHP print $uname;?>" maxlength="20">
Password: <INPUT TYPE = 'TEXT' Name ='password'  value="<?PHP print $pword;?>" maxlength="16">

<P>
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1"  VALUE = "Register">


</FORM>
<P>

<?PHP print $errorMessage;?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Did you do echo mysql_error ?

Comment: Replace
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE USERNAME = $uname";
with
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE USERNAME = '".$uname."'";

And

Replace
$SQL = "INSERT INTO login (L1, L2) VALUES ($uname, md5($pword))";
with
$SQL = "INSERT INTO login (L1, L2) VALUES ('".$uname."', '".md5($pword)."')";

Also check mysql_error();

Comment: Does this question have anything to do with [tag:eclipse] or did you just tag it because you're using Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to rather make use of PDO then you don't have to to do the cleanup of the user input as PDO will take care of that for you.  You might want to creat a file that hold all your connection details like this:

```
   <?php

          define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
          define('DB_NAME', 'user authentication');
          define('DB_USER', 'root');
          define('DB_PASS', '');
          define('DSN', 'mysql:host='. DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME);

    ?>
```

You then might want to create a class to do the connection to your database like:

```
<?php

    class database{

    public function databaseConnect(){
            /*Creates a new instance of the PDO called $db.
             * NOTE: the use of DSN, DB_USER and so on.  These variable live in the dbsettings file.
            */
            $db = new PDO(DSN,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            return $db;
        }
    }

?>
```

Then you might want to create a class to register your user like:

```
<?php

    //Include the database class file to allow access to properties and methods within that class.
    require_once 'class.database.php';


    //echo 'I am database class file now included in the users class file. <br />';

    //This method will be user to check if the user enter the correct username password pair.
    class users{


        public function checkValidUser($username){
            $userExists = false;
            try {
                $db = database::databaseConnect();

                $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT uname FROM table WHERE uname=:username');
                $stmt->bindParam(':uname', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->execute();

                if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
                    $userExists = true;
                }

                $db = null;

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                $userExists = false;
            }
            return $userExists;
        }

        public function addUser($firstname, $lastname, $username,$password){
            $success = true;
            //Connect to the database
            try {
                $db = database::databaseConnect();
                //$db->databaseConnect();

                $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO table (FirstName, LastName, Username, Password) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :username, :password)');
                $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $success = $stmt->execute();

                if ($success){

                    $success = true;
                }

                $db = null;

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                //echo 'There was an error adding a new user.  Please go back and try again.  If this problem persits please contact the administrator.';
                $success = false;
            }
            return $success;
        }


?>
```

Hope that this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602704/why-wont-the-data-be-stored-in-my-database/15602972#15602972)`$SQL = "INSERT INTO login (L1, L2) VALUES ($uname, md5($pword))";`

You're not inserting the values into proper fields, it appears. You're inserting the `$uname` into L1 and `md5($pword)` into L2 but in the select query above, you have a different field name for username and I presume the same for password.

`$SQL = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE USERNAME = $uname";`

Most likely, your insert query should be something like:

`$SQL = "INSERT INTO login (USERNAME, PASSWORD) VALUES ('{$uname}', MD5('{$pword}'))";`

I added single quotes around the username and password since presumably they are strings. Also, I added curly braces around the variables to segregate what is SQL from what is PHP.

One last thing, I would check into doing this with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) as [Willem suggested](http://php.net/pdo)